# WPF Threading Grab Bag

Tags: wpf, multithreading, image, backgroundworker, threadpool

I have developed an interesting WPF control that is currently slowing down my entire application :)  On my custom control, I have an image control that I need to update everytime a backend event occurs.  This backend event is firing twice a second (very fast).  When the event fires I need to pull a Bitmap object out of a 3rd party control, convert to a BitmapSource object and then bind it to my Image control.  Each time my event is fired, I am queuing a new work item in the ThreadPool.  The item will then fetch the Bitmap and do the conversion in a background worker object.  This is done everytime the event fires.  I am using the dispatcher to update my image control source with BeginInvoke but I still get an unresponsive app.  Please let me know what I can do to make this process better performing and help to make my app more responsive:

Here is the code in my event:

```
void inSight_ResultsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ProcessEvent), ((InSightViewer)this.DataContext).CvsDisplay);
        }
```

Here is the code from delegate:

```
void ProcessEvent(object display)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bw.RunWorkerAsync(display);

        }
```

Here is the code in my background worker DoWork event:

```
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            3rdPartyControl displayControl = new 3rdPartyControl();

            displayControl.ImageHost = (ImgHost)e.Argument;


            Bitmap b = displayControl.GetBitmap();

            var mBitmap = b.GetHbitmap();
            BitmapSource bs;

            try
            {
                bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                           mBitmap,
                           IntPtr.Zero,
                           Int32Rect.Empty,
                           BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

                bs.Freeze();
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) { throw ex; }
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(mBitmap);
            }

            e.Result = bs;
        }
```

Here is the code in RunWorkerCompleted event:

```
void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (ThreadStart)delegate()
        {
            this.imgSource.Source = (BitmapSource)e.Result;
        });
}
```

Comment: The BackgroundWorker will do it's work in a background thread. It seems unusual that you'd create the BackgroundWorker on a separate thread (via the ThreadPool) also. Is there are reason for that?

Comment: Try to comment out the begininvoke statement and see if the app is still unresponsive. If it is then it must be some code not shown above that is running on the GUI thread. Is the backend using any COM interop that requires STA?

Comment: The thrid party control is .NET winforms control but I am sure its using some COM/GDI technologies under the hood.

Comment: To check if the problem is COM pumping: Put a Thread.Sleep(10000) after the background worker is started to prevent the GUI thread from pumping. Then put a breakpoint inside RunWorkerCompleted and see if it is reached.

Comment: It didn't seem to make a difference.  If I simulate this whole process with a simple counter textbox that gets updated everytime the backend event fires, everything works perfectly - I get all 120 updates from my first minute of execution - when I introduce the image control, the bitmap conversion and the image source binding the app goes out to lunch.

Comment: oh and I need to use the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or .Invoke as I need to access the image control which is back on the UI thread

Comment: Is the generation and conversion of the image taking longer than the time between events? You could eventually pile up an infinitely long stack, and your application would definitely stop responding. I remember doing game programming once and we would skip display updates if the previous display update hadn't finished yet.

Comment: I would assume that it does take longer, I will confirm that it is. Thats a great suggestion Dan, not sure if the guy I am working for will like that idea. He wants to see every update, it doesn't need to be in real time but all images must be published. I like your thinking though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, (ThreadStart)delegate()
        {
            this.imgSource.Source = (BitmapSource)e.Result;
        });
}
```

System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.**ApplicationIdle** means Operations are processed when the application is idle.

What if the application is always busy and never idle? The requests will be queued and the app slows down.

However I haven't tested this because I don't have the source code of your app.